# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: django, if-statement, nonetype, or-condition

I am if using if statement with or condition
but this is showing error
first I was wrong with none and or condiotns

```
print(farm_acerage)
print(batch_acerage)
print(current_acerage)


if farm_acerage in (None, 0):
   return Response({"error": True, "message": "Add farm first"},
                   status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

if farm_acerage is not None and batch_acerage in (None, 0):
   if current_acerage > farm_acerage:
      return Response({"error": True, "message": "Ckkannot add batch more than farm capacity"},
                      status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

if farm_acerage is not None and batch_acerage is not None:
   batch_acerage = float(batch_acerage) + float(current_acerage)
   if batch_acerage > farm_acerage:
      return Response({"error": True, "message": "Cannot add batch more than farm capacity"},
                      status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The error is

```
2.0
None
1.0
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 2):

`None or 0` will return `0`. Indeed, `x or y` returns *`x`* if the truthiness of *`x`* is `True` and *`y`* otherwise.

You can work with:

```
if batch == None or batch == 0:
   # …
```

or shorter:

```
if batch in (None, 0):
    # …
```

Furthermore your `current_acerage` is a `str`ing, not a `float`, so you can make a comparison with:

```
if batch_acerage in (None, 0) and float(current_acerage) > farm_acerage:
    return Response(
        {"error": True, "message": "Ckkannot add batch more than farm capacity"},
        status = status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
```

Comment: thanks for ur correct answer 
I am also a huge fan of BBT

Comment: None <class 'NoneType'>
2.0 <class 'float'>
1 <class 'str'>
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'